# Why do several datasets have an Array of Structs in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I see that several datasets have an array of Structs inside of an element instead of an Array of String or Integer.

```
 |-- name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I was wondering why because ultimately what I want is to be able to represent an Array of Strings then why have a struct in between.

Comment: A struct can later add more fields. Arrays are only a single type. Why the struct is there depends on your dataset

Comment: @Code Junkie did my answer work for you?

Comment: it depends on you how you want to handle the schema although if you are sure that you can transform the struct into string that should be easy. Please provide some sample data first as well as the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold array of Strings using `ArrayType` and `StructField`. You don't need to use `StructType` inside `StructField`. In the example, column2 can hold array of String. Please see schema for "column2". Nevertheless the schema for the whole row will be a `StructType`.

```
StructType( 
Array(
StructField("column1", LongType, nullable = true),
StructField("column2", ArrayType(StringType, true), nullable = true)
)
)
```

You need a StructType to hold a complex type which consists of many data types. It is like holding a table within a column. Please see schema for "column2".

```
StructType( 
Array(
StructField("column1", LongType, nullable = true),
StructField("column2", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
      StructField("column3", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("column4", StringType, nullable = true))),
 true)
)
)
```

Comment: "don't need to use StructType", then you say you need it ?

Comment: I meant StructType inside StructField is not needed for storing array of String. I am fixing the text. Thanks for the review.